# In R formulas, why do I have to use the I() function on power terms, like y ~ I(x^3)

Tags: r, formula, polynomials, tilde

I'm trying to get my head around the use of the tilde operator, and associated functions.  My 1st question is why does `I()` need to be used to specify arithmetic operators? For example, these 2 plots generate different results (the former having a straight line, and the latter the expected curve)

```
x <- c(1:100)
y <- seq(0.1,10,0.1)

plot(y~x^3)
plot(y~I(x^3))
```

further, both of the following plots also generate the expected result

```
plot(x^3, y)
plot(I(x^3), y)
```

My second question is, perhaps the examples I've been using are too simple, but I don't understand where `~` should actually be used.

Comment: Any excellent answer to this question will draw heavily on what is contained in `?formula`.

Comment: Duplicate; we should close one of these and make the other canonical: [What does the capital letter “I” in R linear regression formula mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192428/capital-letter-i-in-r-linear-regression)

Comment: @smci : You might be right. However, neither of these offered the more statistically correct use of `poly` until I noticed that glaring omission from my answer and included it. It's such a different slant on the general topic of formulas in R that I'm going to add a separate answer.

Comment: @IRTFM: ok then since we can't close older into newer, either we close that into this or at least leave a comment there referencing this question as related/duplicate

Comment: There's a better description of statistical issues involved in polynomial models in regression procedures by @Achim Zeileis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999900/poly-in-lm-difference-between-raw-vs-orthogonal/30000214#30000214

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The tilde operator is actually a function that returns an unevaluated expression, a type of language object. The expression then gets interpreted by modeling functions in a manner that is different than the interpretation of operators operating on numeric objects.

The issue here is *how* formulas and specifically the "+, ":", and "^" operators in them are interpreted. (A side note: the correct statistical procedure would be to use the function `poly` when attempting to make higher order terms in a regression formula.) Within R formulas the infix operators "+", "*", ":" and "^" have entirely different meanings than when used in calculations with numeric vectors. In a formula the tilde (`~`) separates the left hand side from the right hand side. The `^` and `:` operators are used to construct interactions so  `x` = `x^2` = `x^3` rather than becoming perhaps expected mathematical powers. (A variable interacting with itself is just the same variable.) If you had typed `(x+y)^2` the R interpreter would have produced (for its own good internal use),  not a mathematical: `x^2 +2xy +y^2` , but rather a symbolic: `x + y +x:y` where `x:y` is an interaction term without its main effects. (The `^` gives you both main effects and interactions.)

```
?formula
```

The `I()` function acts to convert the argument to "as.is", i.e. what you expect. So I(x^2) would return a vector of values raised to the second power.

The `~` should be thought of as saying "is distributed as" or "is dependent on" when seen in regression functions. The `~` is an infix function in its own right. You can see that `LHS ~ RHS` is almost shorthand for `formula(LHS, RHS)` by typing this at the console:

```
`~`(LHS,RHS)
#LHS ~ RHS

class( `~`(LHS,RHS) )
#[1] "formula"

identical( `~`(LHS,RHS), as.formula("LHS~RHS") )
#[1] TRUE   # cannot use `formula` since it interprets its first argument
```

In regression functions the an error term in model descriptions will be in whatever form that regression function presumes or is specifically called for in the parameters for `family`. The mean for the base level will generally be labelled `(Intercept)`. The function context and arguments may also further determine a link function such as log() or logit() from the `family` value, and it is also possible to have a non-canonical family/link combination.

The "+" symbol in a formula is not really adding two variables but is usually an implicit request to calculate a regression coefficient(s) for that variable in the context of the rest of the variables that are on the RHS of a formula. The regression functions use `model.matrix and that function will recognize the presence of factors or character vectors in the formula and build a matrix that expand the levels of the discrete components of the formula.

In plot()-ting functions it basically reverses the usual `( x, y )` order of arguments that the plot function usually takes. There was a plot.formula method written so that formulas could be used as a more "mathematical" mode of communicating with R. In the `graphics::plot.formula`, `curve`, and 'lattice' and 'ggplot' functions, it governs how multiple factors or numeric vectors are displayed and "facetted".

The overloading of the "+" operator is discussed in the comments below and is also done in the plotting packages: ggplot2 and gridExtra where is it separating functions that deliver object results. There it acting as a pass-through and layering operator. Some aggregation functions have a formula method which use "+" as an "arrangement" and grouping operator.

Comment: I had already read `?formula` (although that wasn't clear from my question); what confused me there is the concept of operators in model formulation.  For example, I'm totally lost as to how the `+` symbol can mean something other than to add two values together

Comment: In a formula within a regression function you are implicitly asking to return a set of (estimated) coefficients associated with (usually multiplied by)  each of the terms connected by "+"'s.

Comment: @ChrisW The `+` operator is overloaded within the context of a formula.  It's done to give a more intuitive feel to formula specifications.  Otherwise regression calls would look like `lm( formula=formula(y.var,x.var1,x.var2) )` which is less easy to understand.

Comment: It's not just the operators that mean different things; it's more fundamentally the symbols. Usually if you type `x + y`, the symbols `x` and `y` are evaluated and their values summed together. In a formula context such as `z ~ x + y`, the symbols do not get evaluated, but the formula refers to these actual symbols. There are various operators for constructing formulas from symbols, and e.g. symbol + symbol does not mean the same thing as value + value.