# Use of ~ (tilde) in R programming Language

Tags: r, r-faq, r-formula

I saw in a tutorial about regression modeling the following command:

```
myFormula <- Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
```

What exactly does this command do, and what is the role of `~` (tilde) in the command?

Comment: Care to share the link to the tutorial? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @cheeesus...I was going through the ebook data mining in R with case studies...there you can find many more of  such interesting examples.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

The thing on the right of `<-` is a [`formula`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/topics/formula) object. It is often used to denote a statistical model, where the thing on the left of the `~` is the response and the things on the right of the `~` are the explanatory variables. So in English you'd say something like *"Species depends on Sepal Length, Sepal Width, Petal Length and Petal Width"*.

The `myFormula <-` part of that line stores the formula in an object called `myFormula` so you can use it in other parts of your R code.

---

**Other common uses of formula objects in R**

The `lattice` package uses them to [specify the variables to plot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lattice/topics/B_00_xyplot).
The `ggplot2` package uses them to [specify panels for plotting](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/topics/facet_wrap).
The `dplyr` package uses them for [non-standard evaulation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html).

Comment: For a slightly more expansive discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055508/the-tilde-operator-in-r/8055683#8055683

Comment: The 'formulas' section of the [`lazyeval` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) gives a good introduction to what a formula is

Answer (score 96):

R defines a `~` (tilde) operator for use in formulas.  Formulas have all sorts of uses, but perhaps the most common is for regression:

```
library(datasets)
lm( myFormula, data=iris)
```

`help("~")` or `help("formula")` will teach you more.

@Spacedman has covered the basics.  Let's discuss how it works.

First, being an operator, note that it is essentially a **shortcut to a function** (with two arguments):

```
> `~`(lhs,rhs)
lhs ~ rhs
> lhs ~ rhs
lhs ~ rhs
```

That can be helpful to know for use in e.g. `apply` family commands.

Second, you can manipulate the formula **as text**:

```
oldform <- as.character(myFormula) # Get components
myFormula <- as.formula( paste( oldform[2], "Sepal.Length", sep="~" ) )
```

Third, you can manipulate it **as a list**:

```
myFormula[[2]]
myFormula[[3]]
```

Finally, there are some helpful tricks with formulae (see `help("formula")` for more):

```
myFormula <- Species ~ .
```

For example, the version above is the same as the original version, since the dot means "all variables not yet used." This looks at the data.frame you use in your eventual model call, sees which variables exist in the data.frame but aren't explicitly mentioned in your formula, and replaces the dot with those missing variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ari B. Friedman but the last line is a bit ambiguous where you say  'dot means "all variables not yet used"'. If you could illustrate it further.

Comment: @Ankita, "not yet used" in this context means not referred to. In `Species~.`, species is the only variable that has been used. Therefore, it depends upon every other variable in the data.frame.

Comment: I don't understand `myFormula <- Species ~ . `. When dot still be substituted with variables from data.frame? Could you provide an example

Answer (score 11):

In a word,

`The tilde`(~) `separates the left side of a formula with the right side of the formula.`

For example, in a linear function, it would separate the dependent variable from the independent variables and can be interpreted as saying, “as a function of.” So, when a person’s wages (wages) as a function of their years of education (years_of_education), we do something like,

```
wages ~ years_of_education
```

Here,

```
 Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
```

It means, `Species` is a function of  `Sepal Length, Sepal Width, Petal Length and Petal Width`.