# What do '~' and '.' indicate in a facet_wrap() argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I've used R for a while now, and still don't know what I'm doing when it comes to using `facet_wrap()`. Consider this, for exapmle:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~ z)
```

It works, but whenever I use `facet_wrap()` I end up just trying different permutations of how its argument should be formatted. This is because I have *no* idea what `~` or `.` mean in these arguments.

Does anyone have a succinct description of what these things are?

Comment: The `~` is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976331/use-of-tilde-in-r-programming-language. The `.` means every variable in the dataset. Thus in `facet_wrap` you are using a formula to define the order of variables (or rather the levels) in the facets.

Answer (score 6):

The `facet_grid` docs state:

*a formula with the rows (of the tabular display) on the LHS and the columns (of the tabular display) on the RHS; the dot in the formula is used to indicate there should be no faceting on this dimension (either row or column). The formula can also be provided as a string instead of a classical formula object*

`facet_wrap` docs state:

*Either a formula or character vector. Use either a one sided formula, ~a + b, or a character vector, c("a", "b").*

The examples in both help pages are designed to illustrate what's going on, but you can mock up your own examples to see what the differences are. e.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()

gg + facet_wrap(~cyl)
gg + facet_wrap("cyl")

gg + facet_wrap(~gear)
gg + facet_wrap("gear")

gg + facet_wrap(gear~cyl)
gg + facet_wrap(c("gear", "cyl"))

gg + facet_wrap(cyl~gear)
gg + facet_wrap(c("cyl", "gear"))
```

That's the best way to get a mental association with the idiom IMO.