# How to create a new list that contain each individual matrix column from an old list in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix, combinations

I try to create a new list that contain each individual matrix column from an old list. For example:

```
var_names <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
var_combi <- list()
for(i in 1:length(var_names)) {var_combi[[i]] <- combn(var_names[1:length(var_names)],i)}
c(var_combi)
```

Then I got a list object like below. Each listed item is a matrix:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "d" 

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "b"  "c"  "c" 
[3,] "c"  "d"  "d"  "d" 

[[4]]
     [,1]
[1,] "a" 
[2,] "b" 
[3,] "c" 
[4,] "d"
```

I want to create a new list `new_list` such as below, e.g.

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]] 
[1] "b"

[[3]] 
[1] "c" 

[[4]]
[1] "d" 

[[5]]
[1]  "a" "b"

[[6]]
[1]  "a" "c"
```

So that I can loop over them or use `lapply` to select those variables from my dataset `mydata` using `mydata[names(mydata) %in% new_list[[i]]]`.

Now I'm struggle to create `new_list` and couldn't find a proper solution for it (I tried `unlist`, `c` and `append`). If I have to use `for` loop, how do I loop over a list and listed matrix columns here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using the functional approach instead of looping, this should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

c(var_combi) %>%
  map(t) %>%
  map(~ split(., 1:nrow(.))) %>%
  unlist(recursive = F)
```

Comment: Magic! But can I have more explanation on the code? I'm not used to pipes yet.

Comment: 1. The first map is taking each matrix your list and passing it into `t()` to make each element n x m, rather than m x n; 2. The second map is passing each matrix element into a lambda function that splits the matrix into one list per row; 3. the `unlist()` flattens this list-of-list into a list of vectors.

Comment: What is the `~` before the `split`? Once I take it out, it shows `Error in 1:nrow(.) : argument of length 0`. Also, is `map` kind of like `lapply`?

Comment: This explains the `~`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976331/use-of-tilde-in-r-programming-language

Comment: This provides context on `purrr::map()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101045/why-use-purrrmap-instead-of-lapply

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward approach using `base R`:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_along(var_names), function(x) {
    combn(var_names, x, simplify = FALSE)
}), recursive = FALSE)

[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c"

[[4]]
[1] "d"

[[5]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[6]]
[1] "a" "c"
.
.    ### 9 more elements
.
```

This is a minor modification of the OP's code. We use here `lapply` instead of a for loop and we also set `simplify = FALSE` in `combn` (the default is `simplify = TRUE`). This argument, if `FALSE`, will leave the result in the requested list format. You will also note that we use `unlist` with `rescursive = FALSE` which stops unlisting after the first level.

If you really want conciseness, we can use the `powerset` function from the `rje` library. We must keep in my that we need to remove the first element which is equivalent to the empty set:

```
rje::powerSet(letters[1:4])[-1]

[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[4]]
[1] "c"

[[5]]
[1] "a" "c"

[[6]]
[1] "b" "c"

[[7]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[8]]
[1] "d"

[[9]]
[1] "a" "d"

[[10]]
[1] "b" "d"

[[11]]
[1] "a" "b" "d"

[[12]]
[1] "c" "d"

[[13]]
[1] "a" "c" "d"

[[14]]
[1] "b" "c" "d"

[[15]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```