# What does the capital letter "I" in R linear regression formula mean?

Tags: r, regression, formula, polynomials

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question, largely because googling anything with a standalone letter (like "I") causes issues.

What does the "I" do in a model like this?

```
data(rock)
lm(area~I(peri - mean(peri)), data = rock)
```

Considering that the following does NOT work:

```
lm(area ~ (peri - mean(peri)), data = rock)
```

and that *this* does work:

```
rock$peri - mean(rock$peri)
```

Any key words on how to research this myself would also be very helpful.

Comment: There is excellent documentation in R. Read `help("I")`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I saw that. That doesn't entirely answer why the special treatment is necessary inside a linear model but not outside of one. If the answer is "that's just how R works" then I suppose that counts.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Of course, but I got in the habit of using the more verbose command on SO because `?[` doesn't work.

Comment: "In function formula. There it is used to inhibit the interpretation of operators such as "+", "-", "*" and "^" as formula operators, so they are used as arithmetical operators." is pretty clear. There is even a helpful link to the documentation of `formula`.

Comment: @Roland, `?'['` or ?`[`

Comment: @rawr Sure, but a newby doesn't know that after being shown `?I`.

Comment: I seem to have exhausted the elaboration and expansion I'm going to get. Thank you for your help.

Comment: To return to the original question: section 11.1 in "An Introduction to R" (ships with your R installation, look under the help menu) gives a few hints. It essentially gives the mnemonic that `I()` = *insulate*. May be helpful. And I'll agree that the documentation on `I()` is, um, *terse*.

Comment: Compare your `lm` code with: `my.peri <- (rock$peri - mean(rock$peri)); lm(rock$area ~ my.peri);`

Comment: Is "insulating" in addition to parenthesis required because it's in a function or moreso because the classes of peri and area are different?

Comment: @Nancy This is nothing to do with classes of elements and all to do with `-` having special meaning in a formula. The parentheses are there because `I` *is* a function so you need them just like you need them on `mean()`. It also (but this effect is secondary) visually indicates what is being protected from the formula parsing code.

Comment: It provides an additional _I_nterpretation step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In R formulas, why do I have to use the I() function on power terms, like y ~ I(x^3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055508/in-r-formulas-why-do-i-have-to-use-the-i-function-on-power-terms-like-y-i)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`I` *isolates* or *insulates* the contents of `I( ... )` from the gaze of R's formula parsing code. It allows the standard R operators to work as they would if you used them outside of a formula, rather than being treated as special formula operators.

For example:

```
y ~ x + x^2
```

would, to R, mean "give me:

1. `x` = the main effect of `x`, and
2. `x^2` = the main effect and the second order interaction of `x`",

not the intended `x` plus `x`-squared:

```
> model.frame( y ~ x + x^2, data = data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)))
           y           x
1 -1.4355144 -1.85374045
2  0.3620872 -0.07794607
3 -1.7590868  0.96856634
4 -0.3245440  0.18492596
5 -0.6515630 -1.37994358
```

This is because `^` is a special operator in a formula, as described in `?formula`. You end up only including `x` in the model frame because the main effect of `x` is already included from the `x` term in the formula, and there is nothing to cross `x` with to get the second-order interactions in the `x^2` term.

To get the usual operator, you need to use `I()` to isolate the call from the formula code:

```
> model.frame( y ~ x + I(x^2), data = data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)))
            y          x       I(x^2)
1 -0.02881534  1.0865514 1.180593....
2  0.23252515 -0.7625449 0.581474....
3 -0.30120868 -0.8286625 0.686681....
4 -0.67761458  0.8344739 0.696346....
5  0.65522764 -0.9676520 0.936350....
```

(that last column is correct, it just looks odd because it is of class `AsIs`.)

In your example, `-` when used in a formula would indicate *removal* of a term from the model, where you wanted `-` to have it's usual binary operator meaning of *subtraction*:

```
> model.frame( y ~ x - mean(x), data = data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)))
Error in model.frame.default(y ~ x - mean(x), data = data.frame(x = rnorm(5),  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'mean(x)')
```

This fails for reason that `mean(x)` is a length 1 vector and `model.frame()` quite rightly tells you this doesn't match the length of the other variables. A way round this is `I()`:

```
> model.frame( y ~ I(x - mean(x)), data = data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)))
           y I(x - mean(x))
1  1.1727063   1.142200....
2 -1.4798270   -0.66914....
3 -0.4303878   -0.28716....
4 -1.0516386   0.542774....
5  1.5225863   -0.72865....
```

Hence, where you want to use an operator that has special meaning in a formula, but you need its *non-formula* meaning, you need to wrap the elements of the operation in `I( )`.

Read `?formula` for more on the special operators, and `?I` for more details on the function itself *and* its other main use-case within data frames (which is where the `AsIs` bit originates from, if you are interested).

Comment: Excellent answer, I tried `X:X` instead of `X^2`  but it still did work, you know why?

Comment: What were you expecting `I(X:X)` to do? I assume it's going to try to apply the sequence operator, as in `seq(from = X, to = X, by = 1L)`. But that doesn't make any sort of sense to me.

Comment: Well, does `X: Y` in a formula mean interaction term between `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Yes `X:Y` (not wrapped in `I()`) means interaction between `X` and `Y`. And this is the point; `:` and `^` and some other operators have **different** uses/interpretations *within* a formula. If you want the usual non-formula interpretation you need to wrap the thing in `I()`.  I don't think `X:X` is going to do anything because it doesn't literally mean `X * X` as that doesn't work for factor variables. `:` means interaction.

Answer (score 3):

`From the docs:`

Function I has two main uses.

- In function data.frame. Protecting an object by enclosing it in I() in a call to data.frame inhibits the conversion of character vectors to factors and the dropping of names, and ensures that matrices are inserted as single columns. I can also be used to protect objects which are to be added to a data frame, or converted to a data frame via as.data.frame.

To address this point:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringi = I("dog"))
df2 <- data.frame(stringi = "dog")

str(df1)
str(df2)
```

- In function formula. There it is used to inhibit the interpretation of operators such as "+", "-", "*" and "^" as formula operators, so they are used as arithmetical operators. This is interpreted as a symbol by terms.formula.

To address this point:

```
lm(mpg ~ disp + drat, mtcars)
lm(mpg ~ I(disp + drat), mtcars)
```

Second line. "Creates a new predictor" that is the literal sum of `disp + drat`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. I'm still confused, though. The documentation for `formula` says:

> "The ^ operator indicates crossing to the specified degree. For
> example (a+b+c)^2 is identical to (a+b+c)*(a+b+c) which in turn
> expands to a formula containing the main effects for a, b and c
> together with their second-order interactions."

So I would think that this code:

```
lm(Y ~ X^2)
```

would give three coefficients: (1) an intercept, (2) a coefficient for the first order term, `X`, and (3) a coefficient for the quadratic term, `X^2`. It does not.

```
X1 <- runif(100)
X1_2 <- X1^2

set.seed(61)
Y1 <- 5*X1 + -4.5*X1^2 + rnorm(100,0,.05)
```

The above code gives:

```
> lm(Y1 ~ X1^2)
> 
> Call: lm(formula = Y1 ~ X1^2)
> 
> Coefficients: (Intercept)           X1  
>      1.0486       0.0343
```

Which is the same as having *no* quadratic term:

```
> > lm(Y1 ~ X1)
> 
> Call: lm(formula = Y1 ~ X1)
> 
> Coefficients: (Intercept)           X1  
>      1.0486       0.0343
```

When I use the function `I`, I get this:

```
> > lm(Y1 ~ I(X1^2))
> 
> Call: lm(formula = Y1 ~ I(X1^2))
> 
> Coefficients: (Intercept)      I(X1^2)  
>      1.0602      -0.1145  ,
```

which captures only the downward curve of the data generating process.

It looks like to get both the main term and the interaction, put both terms explicitly in the model:

```
> > lm(Y1 ~ X1 + I(X1^2))
> 
> Call: lm(formula = Y1 ~ X1 + I(X1^2))
> 
> Coefficients: (Intercept)           X1      I(X1^2)     -0.009738    
> 5.021233    -4.518124
```

This seems unnecessarily cumbersome and doesn't seem to be quite what the documentation promises, though I'm sure I've misunderstood it. (Probably the `poly` function is best for all this, anyway.)

Sorry if I'm a bit obtuse; it's late, I went down a silly rabbit hole ...