# Significance of 'I' keyword in lm model in R

Tags: r

I was creating a linear model for my assignment :

```
lm(revenue ~ (max_cpc - max_cpc.mean), data = traffic)
```

But it throws:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = revenue ~ (max_cpc - max_cpc.mean),  : 
   variable lengths differ (found for 'maxcpc.mean')
```

Then, through trial and error, I slightly modified my code :

```
lm(revenue ~ I(max_cpc - max_cpc.mean), data = traffic)
```

and Bingo!!!It worked well.

But now I am trying to figure out the significance of 'I' and how it fixed my problem. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any effort to solve.

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft please let me know what's so wrong in this question that it need to be downvoted/closed and can I ask you if it seems effortless to solve, why didn't you answered it first than commenting over it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Please provide me link of the question you say its original and mine as duplicate.Thanks

Comment: dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192428/capital-letter-i-in-r-linear-regression

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`I()` prevents the formula-interface from interpreting the argument, so it gets passed along instead to the expression-parsing part.

In the formula interface `-x` means 'remove x from the predictors'. So I can do `y~.-x` to mean 'fit y against everything but x'.

You don't want it to do that - you actually want to make a variable that is the difference of two variables and regress on that, so you *don't* want the formula interface to parse that expression.

`I()` achieves that for you.

Terms with squaring in them (`x^2`) also need the same treatment. The formula interface does something special with powers, and if you actually want a variable squared you have to `I()` it.

`I()` has some other uses in other contexts as well. See `?I`

Comment: Also, when you apply certain operators to two vectors of different lengths, the shorter vector is recycled - its values are repeated until it's the same length as the longer vector.  The "variable lengths differ" error indicates that max_cpc.mean is shorter than max_cpc, and wrapping it in the I() function causes R to do the difference while recycling the shorter vector.

Comment: Further to the variable lengths issue, it also suggests that at least one of the variables was not in the `data.frame` `traffic`. You might want to double check that that is indeed what you wanted.

Comment: @John presumably `max_cpc.mean` is the mean of `max_cpc` and is thereby probably of length 1

Comment: Glen_b, perhaps, or perhaps it was intended as a vector of conditions means sorted on some other variable, or maybe it's a typo, or maybe it's...

Comment: @John max_cpc.mean is the mean of max_cpc's its not a typo.

Comment: @neverKnowsBest can you please explain me the logic in R for recycling the vectors of different length.

Comment: heybhai, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: Sure @John I hope you would be there to help me out.

Comment: Is it exactly the same using I() than calculating the operation previously?
Can I() be used for the predicted variable too?

Comment: Generally it will be the same but it may be possible to contrive a situation where something will be changed in between. It can be used on the left side of the formula as well.