# I() function and its use cases

Tags: r

I have read the documentation about the I() function, but I have a hard time understanding what it actually does.

Could you please explain to me in what cases is it useful and how does it impact the computation in the models below?

```
data(cars)
m1 <- lm(dist ~ speed  + I(speed^2), data = cars)
m2 <- lm(dist ~ speed  + speed^2, data = cars)
summary(m1)
summary(m2)
```

When I try to inspect the differences between:

```
a <- I(cars$speed^2)
b <- cars$speed^2
```

The output of a and b is the same, but the class is different.

Thank you.

Comment: You might find this helpful: [r4ds.had.co.nz/model-basics.html#transformations](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-basics.html#transformations)

Comment: I have added a answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192428/what-does-the-capital-letter-i-in-r-linear-regression-formula-mean) that might give you some insight into `I` function: