# I() equivalent (used in R), what is the Python equivalent?

Tags: python, r, olsmultiplelinearregression

The I() function in R is used to create new predictor in Linear Regression, such as X^2 for example:

```
lm.fit2=lm(medv∼lstat +I(lstat ^2))
```

A good explanation is given here ([What does the capital letter "I" in R linear regression formula mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192428/what-does-the-capital-letter-i-in-r-linear-regression-formula-mean)).

I'm trying to do the linear regression in Python with the same formula and I can't seem to find the equivalent. This code works for a single variable

```
fit3 = smf.ols('medv~lstat', data=data).fit()
print(fit3.summary())
```

but if I try, the below code snippet, it obviously doesn't work correctly.

```
fit3 = smf.ols('medv~lstat + lstat**2', data=data).fit()
print(fit3.summary())
```

Trying the ^ operator also doesnt make sense as Python interprets this symbol as bitwise xor. Does anyone know if there is an equivalent of the same function I() in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, seems to be as simple as:

```
f = 'medv~lstat + I(lstat**2)'
fit3 = smf.ols(f, data=data).fit()
print(fit3.summary())
```

Comment: `statsmodels` uses `patsy` for parsing R-like inputs. [Here's the quickstart](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) which includes the above answer as well as lots of other information.