# How `poly()` generates orthogonal polynomials? How to understand the "coefs" returned?

Tags: r, matrix, regression, linear-regression, lm

My understanding of orthogonal polynomials is that they take the form

*y(x) = a1 + a2(x - c1) + a3(x - c2)(x - c3) + a4(x - c4)(x - c5)(x - c6)...* up to the number of terms desired

where *a1*, *a2* *etc* are coefficients to each orthogonal term (vary between fits), and *c1*, *c2* *etc* are coefficients within the orthogonal terms, determined such that the terms maintain orthogonality (consistent between fits using the same *x* values)

I understand `poly()` is used to fit orthogonal polynomials. An example

```
x = c(1.160, 1.143, 1.126, 1.109, 1.079, 1.053, 1.040, 1.027, 1.015, 1.004, 0.994, 0.985, 0.977) # abscissae not equally spaced

y = c(1.217395, 1.604360, 2.834947, 4.585687, 8.770932, 9.996260, 9.264800, 9.155079, 7.949278, 7.317690, 6.377519, 6.409620, 6.643426)

# construct the orthogonal polynomial
orth_poly <- poly(x, degree = 5)

# fit y to orthogonal polynomial
model <- lm(y ~ orth_poly)
```

I would like to extract both the coefficients *a1*, *a2* *etc*, as well as the orthogonal coefficients *c1*, *c2* *etc*. I'm not sure how to do this. My guess is that

```
model$coefficients
```

returns the first set of coefficients, but I'm struggling with how to extract the others. Perhaps within

```
attributes(orth_poly)$coefs
```

?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have just realized that there was a closely related question [Extracting orthogonal polynomial coefficients from R's poly() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26728289/4891738) 2 years ago. The answer there is merely explaining what `predict.poly` does, but my answer gives a complete picture.

---

**Section 1: How does `poly` represent orthogonal polynomials**

> My understanding of orthogonal polynomials is that they take the form
>
> *y(x) = a1 + a2(x - c1) + a3(x - c2)(x - c3) + a4(x - c4)(x - c5)(x - c6)...* up to the number of terms desired

No no, there is no such clean form. `poly()` generates monic orthogonal polynomials which can be represented by the following recursion algorithm. This is how `predict.poly` generates linear predictor matrix. Surprisingly, `poly` itself does not use such recursion but use a brutal force: QR factorization of model matrix of ordinary polynomials for orthogonal span. However, this is equivalent to the recursion.

[image]

---

**Section 2: Explanation of the output of `poly()`**

Let's consider an example. Take the `x` in your post,

```
X <- poly(x, degree = 5)

#                 1           2           3            4           5
# [1,]  0.484259711  0.48436462  0.48074040  0.351250507  0.25411350
# [2,]  0.406027697  0.20038942 -0.06236564 -0.303377083 -0.46801416
# [3,]  0.327795682 -0.02660187 -0.34049024 -0.338222850 -0.11788140
# ...           ...          ...        ...          ...         ...
#[12,] -0.321069852  0.28705108 -0.15397819 -0.006975615  0.16978124
#[13,] -0.357884918  0.42236400 -0.40180712  0.398738364 -0.34115435
#attr(,"coefs")
#attr(,"coefs")$alpha
#[1] 1.054769 1.078794 1.063917 1.075700 1.063079
# 
#attr(,"coefs")$norm2
#[1] 1.000000e+00 1.300000e+01 4.722031e-02 1.028848e-04 2.550358e-07
#[6] 5.567156e-10 1.156628e-12
```

Here is what those attributes are:

- `alpha[1]` gives the `x_bar = mean(x)`, i.e., the centre;
- `alpha - alpha[1]` gives `alpha0`, `alpha1`, ..., `alpha4` (`alpha5` is computed but dropped before `poly` returns `X`, as it won't be used in `predict.poly`);
- The first value of `norm2` is always 1. The second to the last are `l0`, `l1`, ..., `l5`, giving the squared column norm of `X`; `l0` is the column squared norm of the dropped `P0(x - x_bar)`, which is always `n` (i.e., `length(x)`); while the first `1` is just padded in order for the recursion to proceed inside `predict.poly`.
- `beta0`, `beta1`, `beta2`, ..., `beta_5` are not returned, but can be computed by `norm2[-1] / norm2[-length(norm2)]`.

---

**Section 3: Implementing `poly` using both QR factorization and recursion algorithm**

As mentioned earlier, `poly` does not use recursion, while `predict.poly` does. Personally I don't understand the logic / reason behind such inconsistent design. Here I would offer a function `my_poly` written myself that uses recursion to generate the matrix, if `QR = FALSE`. When `QR = TRUE`, it is a similar but not identical implementation `poly`. The code is very well commented, helpful for you to understand both methods.

```
## return a model matrix for data `x`
my_poly <- function (x, degree = 1, QR = TRUE) {
  ## check feasibility
  if (length(unique(x)) < degree)
    stop("insufficient unique data points for specified degree!")
  ## centring covariates (so that `x` is orthogonal to intercept)
  centre <- mean(x)
  x <- x - centre
  if (QR) {
    ## QR factorization of design matrix of ordinary polynomial
    QR <- qr(outer(x, 0:degree, "^"))
    ## X <- qr.Q(QR) * rep(diag(QR$qr), each = length(x))
    ## i.e., column rescaling of Q factor by `diag(R)`
    ## also drop the intercept
    X <- qr.qy(QR, diag(diag(QR$qr), length(x), degree + 1))[, -1, drop = FALSE]
    ## now columns of `X` are orthorgonal to each other
    ## i.e., `crossprod(X)` is diagonal
    X2 <- X * X
    norm2 <- colSums(X * X)    ## squared L2 norm
    alpha <- drop(crossprod(X2, x)) / norm2
    beta <- norm2 / (c(length(x), norm2[-degree]))
    colnames(X) <- 1:degree
    } 
  else {
    beta <- alpha <- norm2 <- numeric(degree)
    ## repeat first polynomial `x` on all columns to initialize design matrix X
    X <- matrix(x, nrow = length(x), ncol = degree, dimnames = list(NULL, 1:degree))
    ## compute alpha[1] and beta[1]
    norm2[1] <- new_norm <- drop(crossprod(x))
    alpha[1] <- sum(x ^ 3) / new_norm
    beta[1] <- new_norm / length(x)
    if (degree > 1L) {
      old_norm <- new_norm
      ## second polynomial
      X[, 2] <- Xi <- (x - alpha[1]) * X[, 1] - beta[1]
      norm2[2] <- new_norm <- drop(crossprod(Xi))
      alpha[2] <- drop(crossprod(Xi * Xi, x)) / new_norm
      beta[2] <- new_norm / old_norm
      old_norm <- new_norm
      ## further polynomials obtained from recursion
      i <- 3
      while (i <= degree) {
        X[, i] <- Xi <- (x - alpha[i - 1]) * X[, i - 1] - beta[i - 1] * X[, i - 2]
        norm2[i] <- new_norm <- drop(crossprod(Xi))
        alpha[i] <- drop(crossprod(Xi * Xi, x)) / new_norm
        beta[i] <- new_norm / old_norm
        old_norm <- new_norm
        i <- i + 1
        }
      }
    }
  ## column rescaling so that `crossprod(X)` is an identity matrix
  scale <- sqrt(norm2)
  X <- X * rep(1 / scale, each = length(x))
  ## add attributes and return
  attr(X, "coefs") <- list(centre = centre, scale = scale, alpha = alpha[-degree], beta = beta[-degree])
  X
  }
```

---

**Section 4: Explanation of the output of `my_poly`**

```
X <- my_poly(x, 5, FALSE)
```

The resulting matrix is as same as what is generated by `poly` hence left out. The attributes are not the same.

```
#attr(,"coefs")
#attr(,"coefs")$centre
#[1] 1.054769

#attr(,"coefs")$scale
#[1] 2.173023e-01 1.014321e-02 5.050106e-04 2.359482e-05 1.075466e-06

#attr(,"coefs")$alpha
#[1] 0.024025005 0.009147498 0.020930616 0.008309835

#attr(,"coefs")$beta
#[1] 0.003632331 0.002178825 0.002478848 0.002182892
```

`my_poly` returns construction information more apparently:

- `centre` gives `x_bar = mean(x)`;
- `scale` gives column norms (the square root of `norm2` returned by `poly`);
- `alpha` gives `alpha1`, `alpha2`, `alpha3`, `alpha4`;
- `beta` gives `beta1`, `beta2`, `beta3`, `beta4`.

---

**Section 5: Prediction routine for `my_poly`**

Since `my_poly` returns different attributes, `stats:::predict.poly` is not compatible with `my_poly`. Here is the appropriate routine `my_predict_poly`:

```
## return a linear predictor matrix, given a model matrix `X` and new data `x`
my_predict_poly <- function (X, x) {
  ## extract construction info
  coefs <- attr(X, "coefs")
  centre <- coefs$centre
  alpha <- coefs$alpha
  beta <- coefs$beta
  degree <- ncol(X)
  ## centring `x`
  x <- x - coefs$centre
  ## repeat first polynomial `x` on all columns to initialize design matrix X
  X <- matrix(x, length(x), degree, dimnames = list(NULL, 1:degree))
  if (degree > 1L) {
    ## second polynomial
    X[, 2] <- (x - alpha[1]) * X[, 1] - beta[1]
    ## further polynomials obtained from recursion
    i <- 3
    while (i <= degree) {
      X[, i] <- (x - alpha[i - 1]) * X[, i - 1] - beta[i - 1] * X[, i - 2]
      i <- i + 1
      }
    }
  ## column rescaling so that `crossprod(X)` is an identity matrix
  X * rep(1 / coefs$scale, each = length(x))
  }
```

Consider an example:

```
set.seed(0); x1 <- runif(5, min(x), max(x))
```

and

```
stats:::predict.poly(poly(x, 5), x1)
my_predict_poly(my_poly(x, 5, FALSE), x1)
```

give exactly the same result predictor matrix:

```
#               1          2           3          4          5
#[1,]  0.39726381  0.1721267 -0.10562568 -0.3312680 -0.4587345
#[2,] -0.13428822 -0.2050351  0.28374304 -0.0858400 -0.2202396
#[3,] -0.04450277 -0.3259792  0.16493099  0.2393501 -0.2634766
#[4,]  0.12454047 -0.3499992 -0.24270235  0.3411163  0.3891214
#[5,]  0.40695739  0.2034296 -0.05758283 -0.2999763 -0.4682834
```

Be aware that prediction routine simply takes the existing construction information rather than reconstructing polynomials.

---

**Section 6: Just treat `poly` and `predict.poly` as a black box**

There is rarely the need to understand everything inside. For statistical modelling it is sufficient to know that `poly` constructs polynomial basis for model fitting, whose coefficients can be found in `lmObject$coefficients`. When making prediction, `predict.poly` never needs be called by user since `predict.lm` will do it for you. In this way, it is absolutely OK to just treat `poly` and `predict.poly` as a black box.

Comment: Thank you @ZheyuanLi for an exemplary answer to a more-complex-than-first-thought question, especially for sectioning the answer and for providing your own functions. I must admit I'm a little baffled by the methods used, but understand the general purpose. My (evidently rudimentary) understanding of the form of orthogonal polynomials was taken from a data reduction textbook (Bevington & Robinson 2003, pg. 128, eq. 7.28). I assumed the output from `poly` was directly relevant to that, but I was ignorant to the different the way `poly` fits them. Thanks again!

Comment: Applause @ZheyuanLi for an excellent answer. In case it's of interest, a somewhat relevant post is at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457230/r-translate-a-model-having-orthogonal-polynomials-to-a-function-using-qr-decomp/31473582#31473582

Comment: In Step #4 in Section 1, the x in the (x-a) term is UNCENTERED. It took an hour of intense frustration before figuring that out.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. What's the source of the picture in section 1, if I may ask?