# Why predicted polynomial changes drastically when only the resolution of prediction grid changes?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, polynomials

Why I have the exact same model, but run predictions on **different grid size (by 0.001 vs by 0.01)** getting different predictions?

```
set.seed(0)
n_data=2000
x=runif(n_data)-0.5
y=0.1*sin(x*30)/x+runif(n_data)
plot(x,y)


poly_df=5
x_exp=as.data.frame(cbind(y,poly(x, poly_df)))
fit=lm(y~.,data=x_exp)

x_plt1=seq(-1,1,0.001)
x_plt_exp1=as.data.frame(poly(x_plt1,poly_df))
lines(x_plt1,predict(fit,x_plt_exp1),lwd=3,col=2)

x_plt2=seq(-1,1,0.01)
x_plt_exp2=as.data.frame(poly(x_plt2,poly_df))
lines(x_plt2,predict(fit,x_plt_exp2),lwd=3,col=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a coding / programming problem as on my quick run I can't reproduce this **with appropriate set-up by putting `poly()` inside model formula**. So I think this question better suited for Stack Overflow.

```
## quick test ##

set.seed(0)
x <- runif(2000) - 0.5
y <- 0.1 * sin(x * 30) / x + runif(2000)
plot(x,y)

x_exp <- data.frame(x, y)
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5), data = x_exp)

x1 <- seq(-1, 1, 0.001)
y1 <- predict(fit, newdata = list(x = x1))
lines(x1, y1, lwd = 5, col = 2)

x2 <- seq(-1, 1, 0.01)
y2 <- predict(fit, newdata = list(x = x2))
lines(x2, y2, lwd = 2, col = 3)
```

[image]

---

*cuttlefish44* has pointed out the fault in your implementation. **When making prediction matrix, we want to use the construction information in model matrix, rather than constructing a new set of basis.** If you wonder what such "construction information" is, perhaps you can go through this very long answer: [How poly() generates orthogonal polynomials? How to understand the “coefs” returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39031172/4891738)

Perhaps I can try making a brief summary and getting around that long, detailed answer.

1. The construction of orthogonal polynomial always starts from centring the input covariate values `x`. If this centre is different, then all the rest will be different. Now, this is the difference between `poly(x, coef = NULL)` and `poly(x, coef = some_coefficients)`. The former will always construct a new set of basis using a new centre, while the latter, will use the existing centring information in `some_coefficients` to predict basis value on given set-up. Surely this is what we want when making prediction.
2. `poly(x, coef = some_coefficients)` will actually call `predict.poly` (which I explained in that long answer). It is relatively rare when we need to set `coef` argument ourselves, unless we are doing testing. If we set up the linear model using the way I present in my quick run above, `predict.lm` is smart enough to realize the correct way to predict `poly` model terms, i.e., internally it will do the `poly(new_x, coef = some_coefficients)` for us.
3. As an interesting contrast, ordinary polynomial don't have problem with this. For example, if you specify `raw = TRUE` in all `poly()` calls in your code, you will have no trouble. This is because raw polynomial has no construction information; it is just taking powers `1, 2, ... degree` of `x`.

Comment: can't find better words to say thanks for all the explanation and links you provided. I had many questions related to this for a long time. For example, this one. May be I should go to SO more.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225156/orthogonal-polynomial-expansion-and-qr-decomposition

Answer (score 4):

In the first place, the predict lines don't fit the original data. You failed to make `poly` objs for prediction.

```
...
poly_ori <- poly(x, poly_df)    # important
...   

plot(x,y)

x_plt1 = seq(-1, 1, 0.001)
x_plt_exp1 = as.data.frame(poly(x_plt1, poly_df, coefs = attr(poly_ori, "coefs")))
lines(x_plt1, predict(fit, x_plt_exp1),lwd = 3, col = 2)

x_plt2 = seq(-1, 1, 0.01)
x_plt_exp2 = as.data.frame(poly(x_plt2, poly_df, coefs = attr(poly_ori, "coefs")))
lines(x_plt2, predict(fit, x_plt_exp2), lwd = 3, col = 3)
```