# R - linear regression - interpretation of interaction and poly()

Tags: r, syntax, regression

I'm a complete beginner with R and I need to perform regressions on some data sets. My problem is, I'm not sure, how to rewrite the model into the mathematical formula.

Most confusing are `interactions` and [poly](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/poly.html) function.

Can they be understood like a product and a polynomial?

---

#### Example

Let's have following model, both `a` and `b` are vectors of numbers:

```
y ~ poly(a, 2):b
```

Can it be rewritten mathematically like this?

```
y = a*b + a^2 * b
```

---

#### Example 2

And when I get a following expression from fit [summary](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/summary.lm.html)

```
poly(a, 2)2:b
```

is it equal to the following formula?

```
a^2 * b
```

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Both `a` and `b` are numerical vectors.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi I've added details and other short example with question. Could you, please, provide an answer to both of them, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has two fold:

- what does `poly` do;
- what does `:` do.

For the first question, I refer you to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051154/4891738 for a complete explanation of `poly`. Note that for most users, it is sufficient to know that it generates a design matrix of `degree` number or columns, each of which being a basis function.

`:` is not a misery. In your case where `b` is also a numeric, `poly(a, 2):b` will return

```
Xa <- poly(a, 2)     # a matrix of two columns
X <- Xa * b    # row scaling to Xa by b
```

So your guess in the question is correct. But note that `poly` gives you orthogonal polynomial basis, so it is not as same as `I(a)` and `I(a^2)`. You can set `raw = TRUE` when calling `poly` to get ordinary polynomial basis.

`Xa` has column names. `poly(a,2)2` just means the 2nd column of `Xa`.

---

Note that when `b` is a factor, there will be a design matrix, say `Xb`, for `b`. Obviously this is a 0-1 binary matrix as factor variables are coded as dummy variables. Then `poly(a,2):b` forms a row-wise Kronecker product between `Xa` and `Xb`. This sounds tricky, but is essentially just pair-wise multiplication between all columns of two matrices. So if `Xa` has `ka` columns and `Xb` has `kb` columns, the resulting matrix has `ka * kb` columns. Such mixing is called 'interaction'.

The resulting matrix also has column names. For example, `poly(a, 2)2:b3` means the product of the 2nd column of `Xa` and the dummy column in `Xb` for the third level of `b`. I am not saying 'the 3rd column of Xb' as this is false if `b` is contrasted. Usually a factor will be contrasted so if `b` has 5 levels, `Xb` will have 4 columns. Then the dummy column for third level will be the 2nd column of `Xb`, if the first factor level is the reference level (hence not appearing in `Xb`).

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, with `raw=TRUE` can be `poly(a, 2)` rewritten as `I(a) + I(a^2)`?

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped me a lot!