# Excel LINEST() and R lm()

Tags: r, excel, lm

I am having some trouble reconciling the outputs from a regression run using Excel's linest() function and R's lm() function.  Here is my data:

```
1   0.027763269
2   0.032764241
3   0.003759775
4   0.006914974
5   0.064674812
6   0.049696064
7   0.095958805
8   0.106885918
9   0.151314442
10  0.037549397
```

I want to do a cubic regression.  So in Excel I do the following:

```
=LINEST($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11^{1,2,3})
```

where A refers to column 1 above, and B refers to column 2.  I am able to get the following coefficients:

```
-0.001444972    0.023399922 -0.094882705    0.115789975
```

I can also use the regression function in the data analysis tools and get the following:

[image]

As expected, I get the same coefficients as with the linest() function.  Now, when I analyze the same data using R's lm() I get different coefficients.  So i use the following code:

```
lm(y ~ poly(x, 3))
```

where the y's are my column 2 in the data above and my x's are my column 1.  Here are my summary results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 3))

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.027081 -0.014140 -0.007118  0.014450  0.047459 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.057728   0.009137   6.318 0.000734 ***
poly(x, 3)1  0.092795   0.028893   3.212 0.018327 *  
poly(x, 3)2 -0.010159   0.028893  -0.352 0.737149    
poly(x, 3)3 -0.080307   0.028893  -2.780 0.032018 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02889 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7517,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6276 
F-statistic: 6.055 on 3 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.03019
```

As you can see the coefficients are the same.  Interestingly, the F statistc, R squared, adjusted R squared, and residual standard error agree with Excel's output.  What is happening here?

I should also point out that when I run predictions based on either Excel's or R's model above, I get the same result.  Specifically the following code in Excel:

```
=(INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11^{1,2,3}),1)*A2^3)+(INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11^{1,2,3}),1,2)*A2^2)+(INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11^{1,2,3}),1,3)*A2^1)+INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11^{1,2,3}),1,4)
```

run for all 10 observations will give me the same result as the following in R:

```
predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, 3)), data.frame(y))
```

So what am I missing here?  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use raw (and not the default orthogonal) polynomials to make results agree with Excel. Take a look at `?poly` and [poly() in lm(): difference between raw vs. orthogonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999900/poly-in-lm-difference-between-raw-vs-orthogonal)
 for more details.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = T), data = df)
summary(fit)$coef
#                          Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)            0.115789975 0.0560743069  2.064938 0.08447712
#poly(V1, 3, raw = T)1 -0.094882705 0.0420303550 -2.257480 0.06477196
#poly(V1, 3, raw = T)2  0.023399922 0.0086694375  2.699128 0.03561730
#poly(V1, 3, raw = T)3 -0.001444972 0.0005198648 -2.779514 0.03201753
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "x   y
1   0.027763269
2   0.032764241
3   0.003759775
4   0.006914974
5   0.064674812
6   0.049696064
7   0.095958805
8   0.106885918
9   0.151314442
10  0.037549397", header = T)
```