# Defining an infix operator for use within a formula

Tags: r, formula, infix-operator

I'm trying to create a more parsimonious version of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/172698/69374) solution, which entails specifying the RHS of a formula in the form `d1 + d1:d2`.

Given that `*` in the context of a formula is a pithy stand-in for full interaction (i.e. `d1 * d2` gives `d1 + d2 + d1:d2`), my approach has been to try and define an alternative operator, say `%+:%` using the infix approach I've grown accustomed to in other applications, *a la*:

```
"%+:%" <- function(d1,d2) d1 + d2 + d1:d2
```

However, this predictably fails because I haven't been careful about evaluation; let's introduce an example to illustrate my progress:

```
set.seed(1029)
v1 <- runif(1000)
v2 <- runif(1000)
y <- .8*(v1 < .3) + .2 * (v2 > .25 & v2 < .8) - 
  .4 * (v2 > .8) + .1 * (v1 > .3 & v2 > .8)
```

With this example, hopefully it's clear why simply writing out the two terms might be undesirable:

```
y ~ cut(v2, breaks = c(0, .25, .8, 1)) +
  cut(v2, breaks = c(0, .25, .8, 1)):I(v1 < .3)
```

One workaround which is close to my desired output is to define the whole formula as a function:

```
plus.times <- function(outvar, d1, d2){
  as.formula(paste0(quote(outvar), "~", quote(d1),
                    "+", quote(d1), ":", quote(d2)))
}
```

This gives the expected coefficients when passed to `lm`, but with names that are harder to interpret directly (especially in the real data where we take care to give `d1` and `d2` descriptive names, in contrast to this generic example):

```
out1 <- lm(y ~ cut(v2, breaks = c(0, .25, .8, 1)) +
             cut(v2, breaks = c(0, .25, .8, 1)):I(v1 < .3))
out2 <- lm(plus.times(y, cut(v2, breaks = c(0, .25, .8, 1)), I(v1 < .3)))
any(out1$coefficients != out2$coefficients)
# [1] FALSE
names(out2$coefficients)
# [1] "(Intercept)"         "d1(0.25,0.8]"        "d1(0.8,1]"           "d1(0,0.25]:d2TRUE"  
# [5] "d1(0.25,0.8]:d2TRUE" "d1(0.8,1]:d2TRUE"
```

So this is less than optimal.

Is there any way to define the adjust the code so that the infix operator I mentioned above works as expected? How about altering the form of `plus.times` so that the variables are not renamed?

I've been poking around (`?formula`, `?"~"`, `?":"`, `getAnywhere(formula.default)`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055508/the-tilde-operator-in-r/8055683#8055683) answer, etc.) but haven't seen how exactly R interprets `*` when it's encountered in a formula so that I can make my desired minor adjustments.

Comment: they are interpreted in stats:::model.frame.default in c https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed66b715221d2720f5b334470335635bada520b1/src/library/stats/src/model.c#L888

Comment: @rawr thanks. can't say i have any idea what's going on in the C code--I see that they "define" each of the symbols understood by `formula` but they only seem to use `tildeSymbol`. Does this mean anyway that I won't be able to get my own infix without going down to C & defining, say `plusColonSymbol` like is done here?

Comment: @HeatherTurner's answer seems exactly right to me.  If you really want to start messing with expanding formulae, I would suggest starting by (1) looking at the `terms` component of the results of `model.frame()` and (2) looking at the code [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/R/utils.R) ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to define a new operator in this case: in a formula `d1/d2` expands to `d1 + d1:d2`. In other words `d1/d2` specifies that `d2` is nested within `d1`. Continuing your example:

```
out3 <- lm(y ~ cut(v2,breaks=c(0,.25,.8,1))/I(v1 < .3))
all.equal(coef(out1), coef(out3))
# [1] TRUE
```

***Further comments***

Factors may be *crossed* or *nested*. Two factors are crossed if it possible to observe every combination of levels of the two factors, e.g. sex and treatment, temperature and pH, etc. A factor is nested within another if each level of that factor can only be observed within one of the levels of the other factor, e.g. town and country, staff member and store etc.

These relationships are reflected in the parametrization of the model. For crossed factors we use `d1*d2` or `d1 + d2 + d1:d2`, to give the main effect of each factor, plus the interaction. For nested factors we use `d1/d2` or `d1 + d1:d2` to give a separate submodel of the form `1 + d2` for each level of `d1`.

The idea of nesting is not restricted to factors, for example we may use `sex/x` to fit a separate linear regression on `x` for males and females.

In a formula, `%in%` is equivalent to `:`, but it may be used to emphasize the nested, or hierarchical structure of the data/model. For example, `a + b %in% a` is the same as `a + a:b`, but reading it as "a plus b within a" gives a better description of the model being fitted. Even so, using `/` has the advantage of simplifying the model formula at the same time as emphasizing the structure.